# Prism equivalent for Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, prism

I want to use [Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/), but I don't want to use Firefox. Is there some similiar technology to Prism, based on Chromium instead of Firefox?

Thanx for your answers

Comment: I'm not sure about Chromium, but it can be done in Chrome. Go to the page that you want and then Spanner/Wrench>Tools>Create Application Shortcuts. It gives you the options to add to the Desktop and/or Menu.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chrome and Chromium have this functionality built-in. They call it Application Shortcuts. Instructions to use it [are here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710).

> - Click the wrench icon  on the browser    toolbar.
> - Select Tools.
> - Select Create application shortcuts.
> - In the Gears dialog the appears, select the checkboxes for the
>     locations where   you want shortcuts
>     to be placed.
> - Click OK.

Comment: Thanks four your answer. I can remember now... I used that Chromium option some months ago. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a separate environment for a specific browser application, just create a directory for user data, then edit a desktop shortcut and add a directive: --user-data-dir=DIR (see chromium -h or man chromium)